# Clean versioning/change history implementation in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to implement a way of creating a record (`Update`) when changes are made in a MongoDB document, via Mongoose/Node.js/Express. I'm new to Node.js so I was wondering what the best way would be of doing this.

I imagine the record to be something like:

```
update: {
    before: { ... },
    after:  { ... },
    created_at: Date,
};
```

I know it's possible to set up a `pre` function that gets called when another method is called, e.g. `save`.

```
Entry.pre('save', function(next) {
    // create an Update record
    next();
});
```

The problem is, I'm not sure how to determine what was changed in the `save` operation, so it's hard to create a list of updated values.

Can anyone think of a clean way to do this?

Comment: If you want to keep a version of every change when you update a document consider using couchdb instead which versions every update for you

Comment: I didn't know CouchDB had that feature. It might be a huge change to swap to CouchDB at this point but maybe it'll be worth it if it takes away the headache of versioning and rolling back.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this Q&A][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370833/clean-versioning-change-history-implementation-in-mongoose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look at the [Model.js](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js) source. There's two functions in the model prototype that should help you. _dirty() and _delta()

Comment: Thanks Donnie. They're private functions but they seem to do what I want. Maybe I can ask the developer about making public interfaces to them for long-term stability.